# how to filter 2nd drop-down list according to 1st drop-down list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu

I want to filter the 2nd drop-down list based on the 1st drop-down list.

for example: if I select 'finance' from 1st drop-down list, the 2nd drop-down list will show all 'finance' value(accountant, property custodian), and if I select 'academic and research' from the 1st drop-down list, the 2nd drop-down list will show all 'academic and research' value(clerk, HiEd libririan).

this is my current code and its not working:

1st drop-down list:

```
 <select id="search_dept" type="text" name="dept" required>
     <option value="">Select Department</option>
     <option id="111" value="Finance">Finance</option>
     <option id="211" value="Academic and Research">Academic and Research</option>
 </select>
```

2nd drop-down list:

```
<select id="emp_table" type="text" name="position" required>
     <option value="">Select Position</option>
     <option id="111" value="Property Custodian">Property Custodian</option>
     <option id="111" value="Accountant">Accountant</option>
     <option id="211" value="Clerk">Clerk</option>
     <option id="211" value="HiEd Libririan">HiEd Libririan</option>
</select>
```

script:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("search_dept").addEventListener("change", function() {
       // let toShow=':contains("'+this.value+'")';
       // console.log(toShow);
       $('#emp_table select option').hide();
       $('#emp_table select option:contains("'+this.value+'")').show();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Do not provide non-unique IDs to elements. Use a data attribute instead.

Comment: can you show me how you do it sir? I have a problem in syntax thank you sir

Comment: I added a [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67792434/1762224) below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you shouldn't have elements with same id in DOM. 
Second you should have filter attribute in second filter(ex. category).
In code below you can see working example for your question, please add comments if you have questions.

```js
document.getElementById("search_dept").addEventListener("change", function() {
       const categoryId = $(this).find(':selected').attr('category');
       $('#emp_table option').hide();      
       $('#emp_table').val("");
       $('#emp_table option[category=' + categoryId + ']').show();
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="search_dept" type="text" name="dept" required>
     <option value="">Select Department</option>
     <option id="1" category="1" value="Finance">Finance</option>
     <option id="2" category="2" value="Academic and Research">Academic and Research</option>
 </select>
 
<select id="emp_table" type="text" name="position" required>
     <option value="">Select Position</option>
     <option id="3" category="1" value="Property Custodian">Property Custodian</option>
     <option id="4" category="1" value="Accountant">Accountant</option>
     <option id="5" category="2" value="Clerk">Clerk</option>
     <option id="6" category="2" value="HiEd Libririan">HiEd Libririan</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't have any questions sir this solves my problem. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Note: Your First Dropdown value should be in start of second dropdown value

```js
$(function() {
  $('#independent').on('change', function(e) {

    var selected = $('#independent').val().toUpperCase();
    var currentDep = $('#dependent').val().charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    var changedSelected = false;

    $('#dependent option').each(function() {

      var opt = $(this);
      var value = opt.val().charAt(0).toUpperCase();

      if (value !== selected) {

        opt.addClass('hide');
        opt.removeAttr('selected');

      } else {

        opt.removeClass('hide');

        if (!changedSelected) {

          opt.attr('selected', 'selected');
          changedSelected = true;

        } else {
          opt.removeAttr('selected');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="independent">
  <option value="A"> A </option>
  <option value="B"> B </option>
</select>

<select id="dependent">
  <option value="A1"> A1 </option>
  <option value="A2"> A2 </option>
  <option value="A3"> A3 </option>
  <option value="B1"> B1 </option>
  <option value="B2"> B2 </option>
  <option value="B3"> B3 </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not provide non-unique IDs to elements. Use a data attribute instead. For the example below, I provided a data attribute called `"deptId"` which I added to the options.

You can create a jQuery plugin that binds a dropdown to another.

```js
(function() {
  $.fn.bindDropdown = function(bounded, dataAttr) {
    var $self = this, $bounded = $(bounded);
    $self.on('change', function() {
      if ($self.val() == null || $self.val() === '') {
        $bounded.find('option').show();
      } else {
        const id = $self.find('option:selected').data(dataAttr);
        $bounded.find('option').each(function() {
          $(this)[$(this).data('deptId') === id ? 'show' : 'hide']();
        });
        if (!$bounded.find('option:selected').is(':visible')) {
          $bounded.val(null);
        }
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$('#search_dept').bindDropdown('#emp_table', 'deptId');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="search_dept" type="text" name="dept" required>
  <option value="">Select Department</option>
  <option data-dept-id="111" value="Finance">Finance</option>
  <option data-dept-id="211" value="Academic and Research">Academic and Research</option>
</select>
<select id="emp_table" type="text" name="position" required>
  <option value="">Select Position</option>
  <option data-dept-id="111" value="Property Custodian">Property Custodian</option>
  <option data-dept-id="111" value="Accountant">Accountant</option>
  <option data-dept-id="211" value="Clerk">Clerk</option>
  <option data-dept-id="211" value="HiEd Libririan">HiEd Libririan</option>
</select>
```

---

You could take this a step further and make this plugin more robust by adding options. You could provide either a function or an attribute for the source and target.

In this example, I decoupled the data attribute check; and replaced it with a function callback (as an option).

```js
function main() {
  $('#search-dept-1').bindDependency('#emp-table-1', {
    sourceFn: function() { return $(this).data('deptId'); },
    targetFn: function() { return $(this).data('deptId'); }
  });

  $('#search-dept-2').bindDependency('#emp-table-2', {
    sourceAttr: 'deptId',
    targetAttr: 'deptId'
  });
}

/* jquery.bind-select.js */
(function() {
  $.bindSelectDefaults = {
    sourceAttr: null,
    sourceFn: null,
    targetAttr: null,
    targetFn: null
  };
  var _getValue = function($ref, attr, fn) {
      return attr ? $ref.data(attr) : fn.call($ref, $ref);
    };
  $.fn.isVisible = function() {
    return this.is(':visible') || this.css('display') !== 'none';
  };
  $.fn.selectedOption = function() {
    return $(this.find('option:selected'));
  };
  $.fn.bindDependency = function(bounded, options) {
    var
      opts = $.extend(true, {}, $.bindSelectDefaults, options),
      $self = this, $bounded = $(bounded);
    $self.on('change', function() {
      if ($self.val() == null || $self.val() === '') {
        $bounded.find('option').show();
      } else {
        var
          $currOpt = $bounded.selectedOption(),
          sourceId = _getValue($self.selectedOption(), opts.sourceAttr, opts.sourceFn);
        $bounded.find('option')
          .hide()
          .each(function() {
            var $target = $(this),
              targetId = _getValue($target, opts.targetAttr, opts.targetFn);
            if (targetId === sourceId) {
              $(this).show();
            }
          });
        $bounded.val($currOpt.isVisible() ? $currOpt.val() : null);
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

main();
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-row-gap: 2em;
  grid-column-gap: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <select id="search-dept-1" type="text" name="dept" required>
    <option value="">Select Department</option>
    <option data-dept-id="111" value="Finance">Finance</option>
    <option data-dept-id="211" value="Academic and Research">Academic and Research</option>
  </select>
  <select id="emp-table-1" type="text" name="position" required>
    <option value="">Select Position</option>
    <option data-dept-id="111" value="Property Custodian">Property Custodian</option>
    <option data-dept-id="111" value="Accountant">Accountant</option>
    <option data-dept-id="211" value="Clerk">Clerk</option>
    <option data-dept-id="211" value="HiEd Libririan">HiEd Libririan</option>
  </select>
  <select id="search-dept-2" type="text" name="dept" required>
    <option value="">Select Department</option>
    <option data-dept-id="111" value="Finance">Finance</option>
    <option data-dept-id="211" value="Academic and Research">Academic and Research</option>
  </select>
  <select id="emp-table-2" type="text" name="position" required>
    <option value="">Select Position</option>
    <option data-dept-id="111" value="Property Custodian">Property Custodian</option>
    <option data-dept-id="111" value="Accountant">Accountant</option>
    <option data-dept-id="211" value="Clerk">Clerk</option>
    <option data-dept-id="211" value="HiEd Libririan">HiEd Libririan</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your help, it also shows the same concept/flow like the other contributor above.

Comment: @Nowell except they didn’t utilize data attributes. The attribute “category” is not a valid HTML attribute.